# Transformation/Pose of a sphere using a spherical camera model

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-vision

I stumpled upon a problem that is related to the Perspective-n-Point problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective-n-Point) in Computer Vision and the Orthogonal Procrustes problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem).
I'm using a spherical camera model that simply projects any 3d point onto the unit sphere. Now I have N correspondences from 3d world points to normalized 3d points on the unit sphere. My goal is to find the transformation/pose (translation and orientation) of the camera/sphere using these correspondences. I hope image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUY2o.png) makes situation clearer.

If you use a planar camera model you usually would use a Pnp solver but I have a spherical camera model that can see points from all angles.

It might be that I just don't know the name of the problem or solution but I couldn't find anything. Basically, I'm searching for a solution where the ray pointing from the sphere center t to any 3d point p is colinear with the corresponding normalized ray on the unit sphere. So something like this:
(p-t) dot (R*r) = 1
I'm sorry, I'm not a mathematician.

Does anyone knows something about this?
Kinds regards,
Florian